# How to install Amd LibM?

Tags: debian, theano, libm

Im trying to install **AMD LibM** to my linux debian but I dont know how to.

I Downloaded the :

*amdlibm-3.1-lin64.tar.gz*

**AMD LibM Library for Linux®. Built with GCC 4.7.2**

However it just comes with the following folders :  include , lib

What am i supposed to do?
Im trying to use amdlibm with theano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make a tmp folder in your home directory, say you're jj

   `mkdir /home/jj/tmp`
2. move the tarred file to the directory

   `mv amdlibm-3.1-lin64.tar.gz /home/jj/tmp`
3. untar

   `tar zxvf  amdlibm-3.1-lin64.tar.gz`
4. you need to be root or have root priv

   `mv liblibm.so /usr/local/lib`
   `mv amdlibm.h /usr/local/include`
5. complile with gcc or whatever to make a.out executable

   `gcc myfile.c -L/usr/local/lib/lamdlibm -I/usr/local/include`

Comment: What if i dont have root?

Comment: On Python,for example, i have to use virtualenv.